# What is the correct _NT_SYMBOL_PATH for my configuration?

Tags: debugging, windbg, debug-symbols

OK I've been working on this for a while now without knowing where the fault lies with. I have a hunch that it could be `_NT_SYMBOL_PATH` or with the Microsoft symbol server. I'm running local debugging in Windbg on Windows 8.1 and have set the following path for `_NT_SYMBOL_PATH` (see below). I have a directory called `c:\symbols`. Can someone at the very least tell me if this syntax is correct and if not please state what should be the correct ? I'm not running a network or local symbol server.

```
srv*c:\symbols*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

Comment: It looks correct to me. If you're in doubt, run `.symfix c:\symbols` to set the MS symbol server and then `.sympath` to see what it was set to. Use `.reload /f` and `ld *` to force a load of all symbols.

Answer (score 1):

```
.sympath cache*c:\symbols;srv*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

This should work for you.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/symbol-path#combining-cache-and-srv

Comment: Qingchuan Zhang@ thank you. I ran the above command in Windbg command prompt but nothing happened. How do I force Windbg to download the symbols based on this path ? Does this override the  _NT_SYMBOL_PATH environment variable symbol path ?

Comment: @JonnyBGood I think that's expected. The symbols will be downloaded when the debugger detects as needed and stored to the cache.

Comment: Qingchuan Zhang@ thank you. When you say stored to cache do you mean to say that the symbols will be downloaded and stored to the following directory c:\symbols ?

Comment: Yes. You can try to attach to processes such as Notepad.exe and I am sure it will get some symbols cached

Comment: @JonnyBGood btw can you accept my answer? Thanks